# conectar asp.net con sql en otra computadora

Tags: sql, asp.net

He creado una web en asp.net conectada a sql, el problema surge cuando publico la applicacion en el servidor web y esta tiene que conectarse al sql de mi pc para poder acceder a la base de datos.

Segun estuve investigando deberia poner en el web config en la seccion de connection string esto:

```
Data Source=MI_IP;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Donde source MI_IP es la ip de mi pc, 1433 es el puerto por defecto de sql

```
Network Library=DBMSSOCN es indicandole que use TCP/IP,
inital catalog es el nombre de la base de datos,
user id es el usuario de sql,
password es el pass de sql
```

El problema esta en que no he podido conectar mi aplicacion web con mi pc, ahora estoy tratando de conectarla mediante un vpn creando como si fuera un vpn server y un cliente

¿Estoy haciendo el proceso como se debe?
Cualquier sugerencia sobre alguna web con la informacion que necesito o algun video seria de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En base a tu pregunta, deberías mostrarnos el error que sale al tratar de conectarte para darnos una idea sobre como ayudarte.

Abrí las propiedades del SQL server > Seguridad (Security) > Auditoría de Acceso (Login Aduting) y selecciona "Ambos accesos fallidos o corectos" y sino puedes conectar esa bd mediante Entity Framework para que evites el uso de crear la cadena de conexion

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion, la ip que escribi no es mia, es de un ejemplo generico de una web que te proporciona distintos ejemplos de connection strings dependiendo del uso que le daras. En cuanto al error mmm para ingresar a la web necesitas loguearte, el error que me da es de time out y esa informacion esta en la base de datos , lo que hare sera instalar sql server en el servidor y mediante este poder acceder a la base de datos de mi pc, a ver si me deja, luego sera hacer las conecciones de lugar en asp.net, a ver si me deja...